# How can I convert my virtual hosts modrewrite in httpd.conf to use .htaccess instead?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I am moving to a new host that does not allow access to edit httpd.conf or vhosts.conf, so I need to use .htaccess instead.

Here's my existing virtual host conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.dev

    DocumentRoot /path/to/html       
    Alias /sitemap.xml /path/to/html/sitemap.php
    Alias /sitemap.xml.gz /path/to/html/sitemap.php
    AliasMatch ^/sitemap(.*).xml /path/to/html/sitemap.php
    AliasMatch ^/sitemap(.*).xml.gz /path/to/html/sitemap.php
    Alias /robots.txt /path/to/html/robots.php
    AliasMatch ^/robots.txt /path/to/html/robots.php

    <Directory /path/to/html>
        AllowOverride none
        Options all
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Deny from none

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            # The following redirects all directories to root using PATH variables
            # Ex. /abc/def/ redirects to /index.php/abc/def/
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The goal is to get the same interaction using htaccess.

The primary interaction I'm looking for is:

```
sitemap.xml => sitemap.php
sitemap-abc.xml => sitemap.php
sitemap-___.xml => sitemap.php
sitemap-xyz.xml => sitemap.php
robots.txt => robots.php

/abc/def/ => /index.php/abc/def/
```

The above vhosts.conf works just fine on my old host, but I'm unsure how to execute this on my new host with only htaccess.

Comment: Em... you want to define virtual hosts inside .htaccess files? How should the server know it is meant to scan the folder where you pack your .htaccess file if not even a host has been defined?

Comment: Are you saying it's not possible to modrewrite with these patterns using htaccess instead of virtual hosts?

Comment: Ah sorry, seems I missunderstood your goal... Yes, certainly you can do most types of rewriting and redirection in a `.htaccess` style file too. It is only second choice and more complicated in a few cases, but you are without alternative. But I don't see what your actual problem is: the rewriting rules required appear quite straight forward, just as the examples given in the excellent documentation mod_rewrite comes with. Where exactly do you hit problems?

Comment: As long as everything you're rewriting to *is inside the document root*, using mod_rewrite is fine.

Comment: Turns out it was a fastcgi issue with my host.  Pasted in the mod_rewrite commands and I was good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my specific issue was with a hosting configuration instead of a mod_rewrite problem.  But for others, here's my solution:

/path/to/html/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```